# How to improve this little piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm just wondering how to improve this code :

```
pagination.children('li.active').prev().prev().prev().prev().prevAll('li.pgn').css("display","none");
```

I just don't like the `.prev()` chain and I didn't find a way to improve it but I'm sure you know how ;-)

Edit:

pagination is my `ul` which contains a lot of `li` with one who has the `active` class.

I want to select all the `li` before the `li.active` but not the first 5 previous one.

Exemple (forget the `pgn` class):

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="active"></li>
```

That will give this :

```
<li style="displat: none;"></li>
<li style="display: none;"></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li class="active"></li>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML markup, too?

Comment: My current code works, I just tought there was a better solution to do this with a jQuery method I don't know.

Comment: For one thing you can use .hide() instead of the .css call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:gt()` selector.

```
pagination.children('li.active').prevAll('li:gt(4)').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MrvDX/

Comment: pagination.find('li.active').prevAll('li.pgn:gt(3)').css("display","none"); worked. Thanks a lot !

Comment: use .hide() ... much cleaner :)

Comment: Yes I will use .hide(). This solution works but I don't know / understand why.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fact you are doing this this way is indicative of the fact that the design of your page/app can be improved.

Why are you having to find the LI with the active class? Why don't you already know this? Surely it was your app that generated the markup in the first place.

It seems as though you are trying to determine state from markup, which I like to steer away from. You should have an object which tells you which index of LI is selected. Then you can use a much simpler jQ selector to select the indexes you are interested in.

Comment: OP here. I realized you were right so I've saved the active li in a var so I don't have to find it everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**EDIT**

```
var pagination = $('ul');

var len = pagination.find('li.active').prevAll('li').length;
pagination.find('li.png').slice(0 , len-5).css('display','none')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/WU49j/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this...

```
var $prevAll = pagination.children('li.active').prevAll('li.pgn');
var prevCount = $prevAll.length;

$prevAll.filter(function(index){
   return (prevCount - index < 5)
}).hide() //instead of - .css("display", "none");
```

using the filter method and passing a function to it.

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Here's a working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/aTzzK/2/